# How to sync a mysql database to external data source

Tags: mysql, sql, elasticsearch

I have a mysql database table called `search` that I need to keep up to data with an ElasticSearch index. I have already exported the table from the table to the es index, but now I need to keep the data in sync or else the search will become stale quite quickly.

The only way I can think of is by exporting the table every x minutes and then comparing it with what was last imported. This isn't feasible since the table has about 10M rows and I don't want to be doing table exports every five minutes all day long. What would be a good solution for this? Note that I only have read-access to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would leverage Logstash with a [`jdbc` input](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html) plugin and an [`elasticsearch` output](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html) plugin. There's a [blog article](https://www.elastic.co/blog/logstash-jdbc-input-plugin) showing a full example of this solution.

After [installing Logstash](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/getting-started-with-logstash.html), you can create a configuration file with the plugins I mentioned above like this:

```
input {
    jdbc {
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb"
        jdbc_user => "user"
        jdbc_password => "1234"
        jdbc_validate_connection => true
        jdbc_driver_library => "mysql-connector-java-5.1.36-bin.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        schedule => "5m"
        statement => "SELECT * FROM search WHERE timestamp > :sql_last_value"
    }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        protocol => http
        index => "searches"
        document_type => "search"
        document_id => "%{uid}"
        host => "ES_NODE_HOST"
    }
}
```

You need to make sure to change a few values to match your environment, but this should work out without a problem for what you need to do.

Every 5 minutes the query will run and will fetch all `search` records whose `timestamp` (change that name to match your data) is more recent than the last time the query ran. The selected records will be sinked in the `searches` index located in your Elasticsearch server on `ES_NODE_HOST`. Make sure to change the index and type name accordingly, as well as the name of the primary key field (i.e. `uid`) to match your data as well.

Comment: can you explain sql_last_start? also schedule "5m" doesn't seem to work for me. i have to use the cron datetime format ie * * * * *

Comment: @Val  does it provide a way to have some logic applied before indexing data into elasticsearch?

Comment: @PrannoyMittal yes you can use [Logstash filters](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/filter-plugins.html) in order to modify the content of your events.

Comment: @thesaadarshad `sql_last_value` is explained [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html#_predefined_parameters)

Comment: @Val...sorry what i meant was some callbacks or any other mechanism where application code can be executed?

Comment: @PrannoyMittal You have the [`ruby` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-ruby.html) in which you can execute any code