# Optimize saving of mysql SELECT * statement into ES index

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch

Suppose I have a SELECT * statement that returns roughly 1 GB of data. What would be the most efficient way to save this into an ElasticSearch index? So far what I have is:

```
res = SELECT * statement
flush_to_es_after_n_objects = 100
for num, item in enumerate(res.fetchall()):

    if num % flush_to_es_after_n_objects == 0:
        helpers.bulk(self.es, list_of_actions)
        list_of_actions = []
        action = {
            "_index": index,
            "_type": index,
            "_source": item
            }
        list_of_actions.append(action)
```

Is there a more performant way to do this, or a way to 'parallelize' any part of the operation? Basically, I need to transfer data from mysql to es in the fastest way possible as the above pattern is very common in my application.

Comment: Have you checked [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33293965/how-to-sync-a-mysql-database-to-external-data-source) to your other question? It'll be easier and more performant to let Logstash handle this.

Comment: @Val in this case I don't know the schema before the SQL query is performed (it's not our database we're querying).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The other answer I'm linking to does exactly the same, just that you let Logstash handle the mysql -> ES "migration" instead fo reinventing a new Python wheel for copying data, i.e. the code you've written above is equivalent to what's already implemented in Logstash.