# Keeping the elasticseach indexed data in sync with MySQL table data

Tags: mysql, logstash

I am using logstash to index the different data in MySQL DB tables.

```
input
{
 jdbc { jdbc_driver_library => "/opt/logstash/mysql-connector-java-5.1.39/mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin.jar" 
 jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
 jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://<ip number>:3306/database"
 jdbc_user => "elastic"
 jdbc_password => "password"
 schedule => "* * * * *"
 statement => "SELECT name, id, description from user_table"
     }
}

output

{ 
  elasticsearch {
    index => "search"
    document_type => "name"
    document_id => "%{id}"
    hosts => "127.0.0.1:9200"
   }
   #stdout { codec => json_lines }
}
```

The data is indexed properly but how do we keep the data in elastic search in sync with the data in the database tables as the data is updated by the application continuously. I just gave the example of one table but I have multiple tables for which I want to index the data. I searched for the answer but could not find the details.

Comment: this answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33293965/how-to-sync-a-mysql-database-to-external-data-source/33325963#33325963

Comment: So doesn't the **schedule** do the job for you?

Comment: Thank you for the information. Schedule will do the job but I want to get the new ones and only the updated ones in the each schedule (not the entire rows again). Is there a MySQL internal field that tells when the row was updated (date time) or should we add a column and track it by updating it.