# How in Logstash update index with new data?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

I have `PostgreSQL 10` database with table. 7000 new data comes into the table every hour.

In `Logstash 6.4` I have such `.conf` file which create index in `Elasticsearch`.

`.conf`:

```
input {
    jdbc {
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:postgresql://@host:@port/@database"
        jdbc_user => "@username"
        jdbc_password => "@password"
        jdbc_driver_library => "C:\postgresql-42.2.5.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "org.postgresql.Driver"
        statement => "SELECT * from table_name"
    }
}
output {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        index => "table_name"
    }
}
```

**Questions**:

1. How update existing index with new data which appeared in table?
2. What is the maximum amount of data index can store? Could there be an overflow?

Comment: This answer may also help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33325963/4604579

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*How update existing index with new data which appeared in table?*

Index table_name is automatically updated with new entries added to your database table.  However, if any existing entries are updated in database table then they are added into the index as new documents with a new document id. Instead, if you would like the existing document in ES updated, use a column name which has unique values and assign it as document id. This way if an existing entry in database is updated the corresponding document in ES is overwritten with latest values.

Use `document_id => "%{column_name_with_unique_values>}"` in output configuration

*What is the maximum amount of data index can store? Could there be an overflow?*

It depends on your resources really. However, for optimal performance it is recommended to keep your shard size between 20 - 40 GB. If your index has 5 primary shards you can store about 200 GB of data in a single index. Anything above that consider storing data in a new index. Ideally, use time series indices such as daily or monthly such that it becomes easier to maintain for ex. to archive & backup and then purge.

Comment: nice answer , great

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I still have some questions. As I understand you correctly, when we start `.conf` file it run SQL statament which we set in that file. That SQL statement scan full table and add to exist index only new data. Lets say if I want to use time in SQL statement, what I need to do? For exampl e: `SELECT * FROM table_name where data_field="2018-10-27 00:00:00"` How to set current system time? Also Can I use SQL file instead of statement in `.conf` file?

Comment: I set path to SQL file by `statement_filepath`.

Comment: Hi, please ask a new question for the timestamp thing :)